# Cast to an unknown template type

Tags: c++, templates

So I saw code like this:

```
template<class T>
T* safe_ptr_cast(Message& msg) {
    assert(msg.header()->size() == T::size());
    return msg.header()->size() == T::size ? reinterpret_cast<T*>(msg.dest()) : NULL;
}
```

How can the `msg` be cast? Generally, the parameter list needs to have a parameter type `T` in order to let the function recognize what type to cast. However, in this case, the parameter type is explicitly stated. Does this mean `reinterpret_cast` will cast the Message type to its corresponding subclasses?

For example, the `Message` class has a subclass `RequestMessage` with some additional members, a subclass `ResponseMessage` with some additional members as well. I assume the size of `RequestMessage` is `50` bytes, and `ResponseMessage` is `100` bytes. Upon casting, if the `msg` object has 50 bytes, it will be cast to `RequestMessage`, and if the `msg` object has `100` bytes, it will be cast to `ResponseMessage`. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking "does casting work in C++"?

Comment: No. Usually I see the template function must have its input as a template parameter list as well as the output. In this function, the input is explicitly specified, so how can the output is a template type? In the original code, `Message` class has `RequestMessage` and `ResponseMessage` as its subclasses.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. The template parameter list is `class T`; the argument is supplied when you instantiate the function template and call the resulting function: `safe_ptr_cast<RequestMessage>(myRMsg)`. What's "unknown" about this type?

Comment: Ah right. I forgot the usage of template class. You are right. Sorry about this. I haven't used template much in my code.

Comment: OK. Is this problem solved then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand the question, but I think you're asking how does the compiler know what type you want to cast to, because the parameter is always a `Message&`

It does not automagically select based on the size: the assert is there to catch programmer errors.

You have to manually specify what type you want when you call the function: `safe_ptr_cast<RequestMessage>(msg)`

EDIT: I had meant to comment that you may want to look at virtual functions because they might be more appropriate (at least in one situation I can imagine where you'd have a function like this one).

Answer (score 1):

Since the template type can't be determined from the parameter being passed, **the compiler won't attempt to determine the template parameter.**

It must be explicitly specified at the call site.

```
safe_ptr_cast<TheType>(msg);
```